# Supremum/Infimum proof: $\sup \{1/x; x\in A\} = 1/\inf(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Assume that $\inf(A)>0$ and let $A'=\left\{\frac{1}{x} : x\in A\right\}$. I need to show that $\sup(A') = \dfrac{1}{\inf(A)}$.

I think this is quite simple, $\sup(A')$ must be $\dfrac{1}{\inf(A)}$ since $\inf(A)$ is the smallest number to divide by, that is $x > \inf(A)$ for all $x\in A$.

Maybe I made a mistake, but if not is this sufficient? Or, how could I make this more formal?

**EDIT** I could probably make this formal by proving this by contradiction...

Comment: That's not quite right, because there may not be any smallest number to divide by.  An infimum is not always attained.

Comment: To show something is the sup of a set, show that it is an upper bound, and then show that nothing less is an upper bound.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you’ve said is a reasonable intuitive explanation of the result, but it’s not a proof. In order to show that $\sup A'=\dfrac1{\inf A}$, you must show two things:

1. $x\le\dfrac1{\inf A}$ for each $x\in A'$, and
2. if $u<\dfrac1{\inf A}$, then there is an $x\in A'$ such that $x>u$.

In other words, you must show that $\dfrac1{\inf A}$ is an upper bound for $A'$, and that no smaller number is an upper bound for $A'$. Neither of these is difficult, but you need to do them in order to have a proof.

For (1), for instance, if $x\in A'$, then $x=\dfrac1a$ for some $a\in A$, and $a\ge\inf A>0$, so $$x=\frac1a\le\frac1{\inf A}\;.$$

I’ll let you take a stab at (2) on your own.

Comment: 2) By contradiction if there is no $x > u$ than $u$ is the least upper bound of the set or $u=\sup(A')$. Then I am not quite sure where to go...

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: That’s not the best way to start. Try this: if $u<\frac1{\inf A}$, then $\inf A<\frac1u$. But $\inf A$ is the **greatest** lower bound for $A$, so there is an $a\in A$ such that ... what?

Comment: Then $a > \inf(A)$, but I still cannot think of an operation that gets me anywhere with this knowledge.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: There must be an $a\in A$ such that $\inf A<a<\frac1u$: otherwise $\frac1u$ would be a lower bound for $A$, and $\inf A$ wouldn’t be the **greatest** lower bound. But then $\frac1a>u$; is $\frac1a\in A'$?

Comment: Sir;I am having a problem in topology ;The problem is  if every differentiable function on a subset $X$ of $\mathbb R^n$ is bounded then prove that $X$ is compact;I wanted to reach you as you once said you are a topologist ;also I could not understand the answers posted here.

Comment: Sorry to bother you in such a way but had no alternative to reach you

Answer (score 2):

Here, we complete the answer of Brian M.Scott.

For (2): First, we note that since $\inf(A)>0$ then $A\subset \mathbb{R}^*_+$ so if we take $u\leq 0$ s.t $\displaystyle u<\frac{1}{\inf A}$ then any $a\in A$ verify $a\geq u$.

Now suppose that there's $u>0$ s.t $\displaystyle u<\frac{1}{\inf A}$ then $\displaystyle \frac{1}{u}>\inf A$ and by characterization of the infimum of $A$ there's $a\in A$ s.t $\displaystyle a\leq \frac{1}{u}$ so $x=\displaystyle \frac{1}{a}\in A'$ and $x\geq u$ and this allows us to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an abstract way to approach the problem.  As a warm-up, try showing that if $f$ is an order-*preserving* function $\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$ then $f(\inf A) = \inf f[A]$ where $f[A]$ denotes the pointwise image of $A$ under $f$. Roughly speaking this is because the notion of infimum just has to do with the ordering and not with any algebraic structure, but you can prove it rigorously from the definition of infimum.  Once you have done this there is an easy modification for order-*reversing* functions like $x \mapsto 1/x$.