# Prove that $\sup Z=\frac {\sup X}{\inf Y}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two nonempty bounded sets of positive real numbers.

Define $Z=\{\frac{x}{y}:\space x\in X,y\in Y\}$.
If $\inf Y>0$, prove that $\sup Z=\frac {\sup X}{\inf Y}$

This is one of the questions I encountered in the first mathematical analysis course.
I noticed that $\frac{x}{y}$ is bounded above by $\frac {\sup X}{\inf Y}$. Then I assume to the contrary that $w=\sup Z<\frac {\sup X}{\inf Y}$, and want to come up with a contradiction.
In particular, I thought about finding an $\frac{x_0}{y_0}$ where $\frac{x_0}{y_0}>\frac{w+\frac{\sup X}{\inf Y}}{2}$. However, I cannot find it out explicitly.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Note that

\begin{align}
\sup Z &= \sup_{x\in X, y\in Y} \frac{x}{y} \\
&= \sup_{x\in X} x \, \sup_{y\in Y} \frac{1}{y}\\
& = \sup X \, \sup \frac{1}{Y}, 
\end{align}

Where the notation in the last line should be evident.

So we need to show that, when $\inf Y > 0$

$$
\sup \frac{1}{Y} = \frac{1}{\inf Y}.
$$

You can think about it for a bit or look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316706/supremum-infimum-proof-sup-1-x-x-in-a-1-infa) for the solution.

Comment: Can I think about it like using the two identities: $\sup \frac{1}{Y}=\frac{1}{\inf Y}$, and $\sup(AB)=\sup A  \sup B$ for the sets containing positive real numbers.

Comment: Yes, if with $\sup (AB)$ you mean $\sup_{a\in A , b\in B} (ab)$, you can think of it that way .

Answer (score 0):

The 'missing' part of your argument can be completed as follows.

Let $\{x_n\}$ be an increasing sequence of elements of $X$ converging to $\sup X$.

Let $\{y_n\}$ be a decreasing sequence of elements of $Y$ converging to $\inf Y$.

Then $\{x_n/y_n\}$ is an increasing sequence of elements of $Z$ converging to $\sup X/\inf Y$.

Hence $\sup Z\ge \sup X /\inf Y$.